# How to structure Swift code with several related CGPoint arrays

Tags: swift, class, struct, swift3

Pardon me if this sounds quite trivial. I am trying to find a way to organize my code, whether creating a new class or a data structure of some sort. I have several CGPoints,

```
var arrayOfPoints = [P1, P2, P3, P4, P5,..,P30]
```

When one is randomly selected, it can move to a number of other points based on the complexity value `compVal`.
For example, if `compVal` = 1, `P1` can move to `[P2, P5]`, and if `compVal = 2`, P1 can move to `[P3, P4, P6]` and so on till `compVal = 15`, this applies to all other P's to `P30`. How can I structure this functionality in such a way that is orderly and efficient, bearing in mind that I may need to filter some of the positions out occasionally?

Comment: i don't understand you question well. better show some code what you do just now. and maybe pseudocode what you like to do

Comment: maybe (i just only guess) you like to have a graph representation?

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/152046/swift-algorithm-club-graphs-adjacency-list

Comment: Is the number of possible points always compVal + 1?

Comment: Do you need to manually specify the possible points for each compVal, or can they be a random selection of points (p1 to p30)?

Answer (score 1):

From my interpretation of the question, it sounds like:

- You have a list of objects
- Each object has an initial `CGPoint`, and has a way of mapping an `Int` (`compVal`) to a new array of `[CGPoint]`.

Based on this, you could have a structure like:

```
struct MyPoint {
    var location: CGPoint
    var mappings: [Int: [CGPoint]]

    mutable func move(compVal: Int) {
        if let possiblePoints = mappings[compVal] {
            // possiblePoints is your [CGPoint] array.
            // Set `location` to one of them depending on your logic.
        }
    }
}
```

You can then create `var arrayOfPoints` as `[MyPoint]`.